# Python capturing terminal output

Tags: python

Hey i run into a problem which is how python can capture the output like this command

```
os.system("apt install apt-transport-https")
```

and then if its allready installed to skip it so it dont make a new install ?

Comment: can you clarify what exactly you want to do?

Comment: reading terminal output is done by `stdout.readline()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
command = 'apt install apt-transport-https'
r = os.popen(command) #Execute command
info = r.readlines()  #read command output
for line in info:  #handle output line by line
    line = line.strip('\r\n')
    print line
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `os.popen` or `subprocess`:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

process = Popen(['apt', 'install', 'apt-transport-https'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
print(stdout)
```

With the output captured in `stdout`, you can search that string for the results you want.